# Python to continue receive click event output from Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, events

I am trying to develop a tool for user to create a simple RPA for themselves by recording the clicking in browser. Using Selenium library, I can execute an event listener javascript into the browser with the return of the clicking node.

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome()

test = driver.get('https://www.google.com')

js_script = "var resp = arguments[0]; document.addEventListener('click', function(e) { resp(e.path);}, true)"
response = driver.execute_async_script(js_script)

print(response)
```

this only able to record the first time click in the browser. How can I continue listen for the Javascript event return in Python whenever the click is triggered in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "execute_async_script" awaits a callback from javascript.

Once the awaited (by Python) callback "arguments[0]" is called then, even though the EventListener is still up on the browser, Python got its callback. The function execute_async_script is thus done for.

You can either create a logic in Python that evaluates the value in the response, and according to that recreates another script or do the logic directly in Javascript something like: (User needs to press "q" in order to terminate the event)

```
js_script = """
//Callback function
var done = arguments[arguments.length - 1]; 
//Take all the events
var array_events = []

var retour = (e) => {
    array_events.push(e.path)
}

var quit = (key) => {
    console.log(array_events);
    (key.keyCode == 81 )? done(JSON.stringify(array_events)) : undefined
}
// Listen to the clicks
getPath = document.addEventListener("click", retour, true)
// Listen to the key "q" which means user has gathered all needed events
getKey = document.addEventListener("keydown", quit, true)

"""
response = driver.execute_async_script(js_script)
print(response)
```